horizontal bars brackets
With the fourier package the horizontal bars of the brackets are almost invisible. How to enlarge them?
Thanks in advance
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}



$\displaystyle{\left[\frac{1}{n}\right]}$
\end{document}


the shape of characters is the artistic choice of the font designer, if you don't like the shape, the natural thing to do is choose a different font.

unrelated but the {..} here are not doing anything.

You could use the brackets in the Utopia part of mathdesign, but I advise not.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mdoperators}{OT1}{mdput}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{mdoperators}{bold}{OT1}{mdput}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdlargesymbols}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{mdlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mdput}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {mdoperators}{"5B}{mdlargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{mdoperators}{"5D}{mdlargesymbols}{"03}

\begin{document}

$[\bigl[\Bigl[\biggl[\Biggl[\Biggr]\biggr]\Bigr]\bigr]]$

\end{document}


For comparison, the fourier brackets: I don't find that the horizontal parts are “invisible”. To the contrary, I find them much more elegant.




I probably would not do this, a font as a whole is an artistic creation of the font designer and chosing individual characters from different fonts doesn't generally make for a coherent work, but...
If you want to pull [] from the default computer modern after changing to use the fourier package:
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmoperators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {cmoperators}{"5B}{cmlargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{cmoperators}{"5D}{cmlargesymbols}{"03}

\begin{document}


$\displaystyle \left[\frac{1}{n}\right]$
\end{document}


Thanks you very much for your answer
